# Transcription via OpenAi's whisper: AssertionError: incorrect audio shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, openai-api, openai-whisper

I'm trying to use OpenAI's open source Whisper library to transcribe audio files.

Here is my script's source code:

```
import whisper

model = whisper.load_model("large-v2")

# load the entire audio file
audio = whisper.load_audio("/content/file.mp3")
#When i write that code snippet here ==> audio = whisper.pad_or_trim(audio) the first 30 secs are converted and without any problem they are converted.

# make log-Mel spectrogram and move to the same device as the model
mel = whisper.log_mel_spectrogram(audio).to(model.device)

# detect the spoken language
_, probs = model.detect_language(mel)
print(f"Detected language: {max(probs, key=probs.get)}")

# decode the audio
options = whisper.DecodingOptions(fp16=False)
result = whisper.decode(model, mel, options)

# print the recognized text if available
try:
    if hasattr(result, "text"):
        print(result.text)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error while printing transcription: {e}")

# write the recognized text to a file
try:
    with open("output_of_file.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(result.text)
        print("Transcription saved to file.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error while saving transcription: {e}")
```

In here:

```
# load the entire audio file
audio = whisper.load_audio("/content/file.mp3")
```

when I write below: " audio = whisper.pad_or_trim(audio) ", the first 30 secs of the sound file is transcribed without any problem and language detection works as well,

but when I delete it and want the whole file to be transcribed, I get the following error:

> AssertionError: incorrect audio shape

What should I do? Should I change the structure of the sound file? If yes, which library should I use and what type of script should I write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and after some digging I found that `whisper.decode` is meant to extract metadata about the input, such as the language, and hence the limit to 30 seconds. (see source code for decode function [here](https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/whisper/decoding.py#L780))

In order to transcribe (even audio longer than 30 seconds) you can use `whisper.transcribe` as shown in the following snippet

```
import whisper

model = whisper.load_model("large-v2")

# load the entire audio file
audio = whisper.load_audio("/content/file.mp3")

options = {
    "language": "en", # input language, if omitted is auto detected
    "task": "translate" # or "transcribe" if you just want transcription
}
result = whisper.transcribe(model, audio, **options)
print(result["text"])
```

You can find some documentation of the [transcribe method](https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/whisper/transcribe.py#L36) in the source code along with  some documentation about the [DecodingOptions structure](https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/whisper/decoding.py#L79)

Comment: Thank you! Actually one of the software engineers working on transcribe library in OpenAI answered the question showing the same whisper.transcribe() method in GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One of the edge cases where chatgpt couldn't find the correct answer for more than 30 minutes but took me few seconds on stackoverflow